# Quick PHP regex for digit format

Tags: php, regex

I just spent hours figuring out how to write a regular expression in PHP that I need to only allow the following format of a string to pass:

```
(any digit)_(any digit)
```

which would look like:

```
219211_2
```

so far I tried a lot of combinations, I think this one was the closest to the solution:

```
/(\\d+)(_)(\\d+)/
```

also if there was a way to limit the range of the last number (the one after the underline) to a certain amount of digits (ex. maximal 12 digits), that would be nice.

I am still learning regular expressions, so any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are the parentheses actually part of the string - in other words are you looking for `(123)_(456)` or are you looking for `123_456`?

Comment: Nope, question answered, thank you all for the time :)

Comment: Many people spend hours finding out `\d` means digit. And, there is no limit to what an expression can match. What do you mean by format of a string? Is this an input field, lines of a text file, just trying to learn regular expressions, etc...? A little background would be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
\d+_\d{1,12}(?!\d)
```

Will match "anywhere in the string". If you need to have it either "at the start", "at the end" or "this is the whole thing", then you will want to modify it with anchors

```
^\d+_\d{1,12}(?!d)      - must be at the start
\d+_\d{1,12}$           - must be at the end
^\d+_\d{1,12}$          - must be the entire string
```

demo:    http://regex101.com/r/jG0eZ7

Explanation:

```
\d+      - at least one digit
_        - literal underscore
\d{1,12} - between 1 and 12 digits
(?!\d)   - followed by "something that is not a digit" (negative lookahead)
```

The last thing is important otherwise it will match the first 12 and ignore the 13th. If your number happens to be at the end of the string and you used the form I originally had `[^\d]` it would fail to match in that specific case.

Thanks to @sln for pointing that out.

Comment: The `[^\d]` requires a character, it won't match `this90_789` Using `(?!\d)` instead might work.

Comment: @sln thanks for spotting that. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need double escaping `\\d` in PHP.

Use this regex:

```
"/^(\d+)_(\d{1,12})$/"
```

- `\d{1,12}` will match 1 to 12 digist
- Better to use line start/end anchors to avoid matching unexpected input

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$regex= '~^/(\d+)_(\d+)$~';
$input= '219211_2';
if (preg_match($regex, $input, $result)) {
 print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Code dumps aren't answers.  Please explain what this code does and how it helps solve the problem.  Maybe you should explain how the regex works.

Comment: +1 Perfect example. The OP spent hours finding out what a regex digit construct is. Now he knows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
^(\d+)_(\d{1,12})$
```